# report user password (in the sharepoint intergrated mode) must be changed when the the AD user password changed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, reporting-services

I am administrating my company's sharepoint server 2016 and I have developed some reports for some sharepoint website, if I want to publish these reports to sharepoint website, I have to key in my user name and password with intergrated mode in the authentication form. 
The problem is all users of Sharepoint (included my admin account) is managed in Active Directory. However, after each three months, all user password must be changed(company rule), so that all of authentication setting in these report become to wrong, and I need to key in new password foreach report again EACH 3 MONTHS.
I don't want to reinput my password for each 3 months but I don't know how to do. Can anyone advise me how to resolve the problem. Thank to your help!
Notes: I'm not AD admin so I can't do any action on the AD.

Answer (score 2):

If I got it right, you are managing reports with an account, and the account's password is renewed every 3 months. For this purpose, you should have a so called service account requested from your company, and the account's password should be set to **not** expire. Service accounts are the way to go for managing authentication-locked tasks which do not require user activity and manual steps.

It should be a relatively ordinary scenario for an organization to have service accounts which are excluded from the password renewal policy. Additionally, this is the only way to handle such scenarios with AD managed accounts.

Comment: thank for your rely. But I don't administrate AD server and my company doesn't allow creating new user with never expire password. I only administrate Sharepoint server 2016, so that I only can act on sharepoint 2016 scope.

Comment: I must put emphasis on the words I've already mentioned: you need to ask support from your AD administrators (=> no, you are not even supposed to be able to handle this by yourself); this shouldn't be an unexceptional scenario; and there are no other ways to handle the requirement. To put it into other words: If there's a reason why you wouldn't be able to communicate with your AD administrators, then there is no solution for your issue.